# "In the Philippines", or "In the US" sounds okay, but why not "In the Japan", or "In the China"?

Tags: articles

Random thought earlier.

I am basing my question on my memory of what seems to be normally used, but I am unsure of the actual correct grammar usage.

Which is correct, and if one is wrong, what is the reason for that?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/which-one-is-correct-in-the-usa-or-in-usa

Comment: You could, if using the archaic names for these nations, say _in the Japans_ or _in the Cathays_.